# XML Tags For Warnings/Important Comments When Documenting C# Code

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

Are there any xml tags recognised by any official C# documentation (and recognised by IntelliSense) that are used exclusively for content that serves as a warning or very important information regarding the use a class or method etc?

Failing that, what is the best way of documenting a warning or important information in XML comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there is any specific dedicated tag for doing this. In the few instances that I've needed to add warnings/important comments to methods, I used the `remarks` tag e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// General info on the method
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>WARNING: Important information on the method</remarks>
public void Method()
{
    // Method content
}
```